# NullPointerException in Adding Buttons from ArrayList to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, nullpointerexception, jpanel

I'm getting an NullPointerException and I don't know why. If someone could look over my code and tell me what is wrong with it, that would be great.

Prompt: Build a pyramid of buttons with inputs of 
1) Block Width
2) Block Height
3) Row Numbers

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class BlockPyramidBuilder extends JPanel{

public static int height;
public static int width;
public static int rowNum;
public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public static Graphics g;
public static BlockPyramidBuilder test;

public static void main(String[]Args){
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Block Height ------->" );
    height = inputReader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Block Width ------->" );      
    width = inputReader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Row Num ------->" );
    rowNum = inputReader.nextInt();

    test = new BlockPyramidBuilder(height, width, rowNum);

    frame.add(test);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
public BlockPyramidBuilder(int height, int width, int rowNum){
    ArrayList<MyBox> array = new ArrayList<MyBox>();
    int center = frame.getWidth();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;          


    for(int i = 1; i <= rowNum; i++){
        y = height * (i-1);
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            x = center + (width/2) * j;
            System.out.println("x: " + x + "      y: " + y);

            MyBox r = new MyBox(x, y, width, height);
            array.add(r);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        test.add(array.get(i));
    }

}

}
class MyBox extends JButton{
public MyBox(int x, int y, int height, int width){
    super();
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(37, 80, 130));
    setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 0, 24));
    setForeground(new java.awt.Color(38,38,38));
    setSize(height, width);
    setLocation(x, y);

}
}
```

The code gets the right coordinates to draw the boxes, however there is an error in adding the MyBoxes to the JPanel. Also, I was wondering

Comment: `Also, I was wondering`?  Wondering what?  Wondering how we'd help you without a stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor BlockPyramidBuilder you reference the test object that is not set until the constructor completes.

Answer (score 1):

`test` isn't initialized before calling the constructor, and you attempt to use it in the constructor. Therefore, you get a `NullPointerException`

In addition, you shouldn't be declaring all those variables `static`. You have a class, it should have instance variables.